# Vue and ripple effect on any element

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

how could I remake [this ripple effect](https://codepen.io/WinterCore/pen/aLBzJq) to not always be a **DIV**? I will give an example

When I use it this way:

```
<ripple class="btn">send</ripple>
```

That's how it works, but when I want to use a button, it always turns into div. Is there any way I could use it this way?

```
<div class="ripple">div example</div>
<button type="submit" class="ripple></button>
```

Or just to use it on any element. No automatic change to div? Next, when I click and hold, the effect disappears automatically in a moment. How to do it to disappear smoothly?

**Could anyone help me with this please?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always div because in the ripple component's template, the wrapper tag is div.
you can change it to other tag you want to use.

as for the disappearing effect, you can set a timer when clicked to start disappearing even when you hold.
like this:

```
addRipple(e) {
  ...
  setTimeout(this.purgeRipples, 600)
},
```

Comment: Thanks, can the template be made dynamically? If the element is div so this template if is a button so with this template?

Comment: pass in a prop to the component, and change the wrapper tag to <component :is="propElType">

Comment: Is that really so easy? Thank you very much for your help! I didn't know about this at all. Solved!